# Deslect targeted enemy question. How to change back to original color

Tags: c#, unity, rendertargets

In the code below I have now:

- Press tab, enemy changes green.
- Press tab again, (deselecting the target) **enemy changes to blue**.

What I want to happen:

- Press tab, enemy changes to green.
- Press tab again, (deselecting the
  target) **green goes away**. (enemy is its **original color**)

Here is my current code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Targetting : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Transform> targets;
    public Transform selectedTarget;

    private Transform myTransform;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        targets = new List<Transform>();    
        selectedTarget = null;
        myTransform = transform; 

        AddAllEnemies();
    }

    public void AddAllEnemies()
    {
        GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

        foreach(GameObject enemy in go)
            AddTarget(enemy.transform);
    }

    public void AddTarget(Transform enemy)
    {
        targets.Add(enemy);
    }


    private void SortTargetsByDistance()
    {
        targets.Sort(delegate(Transform t1,Transform t2) { 
                return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position)); 
                });
    }


    private void TargetEnemy()
    {
        if(selectedTarget == null)
        {
            SortTargetsByDistance();
            selectedTarget = targets[0];
        }
        else 
        {
            int index = targets.IndexOf(selectedTarget);

            if(index < targets.Count -1)
            {
                index++; 
            }
            else
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            DeselectTarget();
            selectedTarget = targets[index];
        }
        SelectTarget(); 
    }

    private void SelectTarget()
    {
        selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }

    private void DeselectTarget()
    {
        selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
        selectedTarget = null;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            TargetEnemy();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So absolutely nothing happens when you target a sprite? Are you sure your targeting code is even working (i.e. it's not the colouring but the targeting)?

Comment: Holy cow, these responses were quick!
@ashes999 I can get the enemy to turn green when I hit the tab key.I hit it again, and they turn blue. So the code works. Its just I want to change what happens when I hit tab.

Comment: Why was this marked as closed? Its pretty clear what he is asking...

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectTarget` method, try changing

`selectedTarget.GetComponent().color = Color.red;`

to

`selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.red;`

Same for your `DeselectTarget` method.

`selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;`